# How to use Starts with and containing together in search query Jpa?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I want to sort my results on the basis of 'starts with' query followed by results from 'containing' query. How to achieve this using JPA, Spring and Mysql ?

Comment: can you show a query model you wanted to be like.(select * from ?), and give some more details so that people can help you better

Comment: select * from entity where name like 'input%' or name like '%input%'

Comment: i want to display the results in order of(starting with terms) followed by (containing terms)

Answer (score 0):

> i want to display the results in order of(starting with terms)
>   followed by (containing terms)

That's not possible with pure SQL because sorting happens on the result and not on a part of the where condition.